# Inno Setup - Transparent Splash Screen

Tags: inno-setup, splash-screen

I have a problem and I need your help..I want to find a differente way to put a transparent splash screen or the correction of my code. The code here works... but there is a problem, some people get an error at the end of the installation.

This is how look the error at the end of the installation
[image]

[image]

I check another lines in my code and I found that the problem was the code of the splash screen, if I delete it the installer works perfect, I see that what I need is a `procedure DeinitializeSetup();` but I don't know how tu put it in the splash screen section, I get this kind of error if I delete the `procedure DeinitializeSetup();` in another codes, like skin, logo, etc.. the files that goes to temp folder of windows... then what I need is the `procedure DeinitializeSetup();` in the splash screen code to solve this... :( here is the dll file for anyone to test [IsUtilsHb.dll](http://www.mediafire.com/?0nawon231dtma5e)

then...please if anybody know a different way to put a transparent splash screen... ill be grateful.. or better.. to fix this code section :)

```
[setup]
AppName=Slash PNG
AppVerName=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\program

[Languages]
Name: "spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"

[Files]
Source: IsUtilsHb.dll; DestDir: {app}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: SplashScreen.png; DestDir: {app}; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
function SplashScreen(hWnd: Integer; pathPng: String; nSleep: Integer): Integer;
external 'SplashScreen@files:IsUtilsHb.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard();
var 
  SplashFileName: string;
begin
  SplashFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\SplashScreen.png');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('SplashScreen.png');
  SplashScreen(StrToInt(ExpandConstant('{hwnd}')), SplashFileName, 5000);
end;
```

Comment: If you'd like transparent animated PNG slideshow, you can take a look at [`Inno Image Animator`](http://code.google.com/p/inno-image-animator/wiki/Introduction). But if you want, I can quite easily modify it to just one image (as a new FOS project) with specifications you tell ;-)

Answer (score 2):

After looking all around the internet, I got this solution:

This is the `DLL` am using:
[isgsg.dll](http://www.mediafire.com/?abiq39n9zumj12w)

```
[setup]
AppName=Slash PNG
AppVerName=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\program

[Languages]
Name: "spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"

Source: "Splash.png"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: ignoreversion dontcopy nocompression
Source: isgsg.dll; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: ignoreversion dontcopy nocompression

[Code]
procedure ShowSplashScreen(p1:HWND;p2:string;p3,p4,p5,p6,p7:integer;p8:boolean;p9:Cardinal;p10:integer); external 'ShowSplashScreen@files:isgsg.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Splash.png');
  ShowSplashScreen(WizardForm.Handle,ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Splash.png'),1000,3000,1000,0,255,True,$FFFFFF,10);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just added:

```
ShowSplashScreen(WizardForm.Handle,ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Splash.png'),1000,3000,1000,0,255,True,$FFFFFF,10);
```

Interpretation:

```
ShowSplashScreen(WizardForm.Handle,ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Splash.png'),1000(appear time),3000(show time),1000(disappear time),0(like a intermittent reload time),255(transparency 0..255),True,$FFFFFF (transparency color if not png transp),10);
```

like a `intermittent reload time = use 9999999` and you see like a thunder image