# Display Splash Screen while running setup in silent or very silent mode

Tags: inno-setup, splash-screen, pascalscript, issi

I want to run a setup but display nothing else but a splash screen. I am currently using the logic suggested in this answer
to run the setup in background:
[How to make the silent installation by using Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21575241/833111#21577388)

However, I want to show a simple image during the installation that disappears once the setup is done. I think we can use the `InitializeSetup` and `DeinitializeSetup` functions, but I am not sure how.

After reading the question [How to hide the splash screen in verysilent mode setup of Inno Setup using ISSI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075156/how-to-hide-the-splash-screen-in-verysilent-mode-setup-of-inno-setup-using-issi), it seems like ISSI (Inno Setup Script Includes) has this sort of feature. But ISSI is unavailable for download since its website is dead.

Additionally I also tried answers suggested in this question [Inno Setup - Transparent Splash Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212559/inno-setup-transparent-splash-screen), but that seems to work only on `InitializeWizard` and not on `InitializeSetup`.

So, how can I run a background setup but only display a image (jpeg, png or gif)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display splash screen, just display the form and never hide it. Like this:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  SplashForm: TSetupForm;
begin
  if WizardSilent then
  begin
    SplashForm := CreateCustomForm;
    SplashForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
    SplashForm.Position := poScreenCenter;
    SplashForm.ClientWidth := ScaleX(500);
    SplashForm.ClientHeight := ScaleY(350);
    SplashForm.Show;

    // Put some image/contents to the splash screen here
  end;
end;
```

---

Though I'm not sure there's a way to hide the wizard in the silent mode. That might be a topic for a separate question.

Though actually, in the silent mode, you can turn the wizard itself into the splash screen by covering it with the image.